# How to change stock quantity in KMyMoney investment editor?

Tags: software, kmymoney

I'm playing with KMyMoney for my personal finances' management, and got stuck with investments. While all the rest seems to be working properly, the "Quantity" field for investments seems to be always 0.00 and nowhere can I find how to change that.

Any help?

Comment: I'd bet you'll have far more success at their forum http://forum.kde.org than here. After reading the question, I loaded KMM onto my Linux virtual machine, and it seems pretty amateurish. You really plan to use it, or just tinkering?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I actually think its rather nice for personal finance management use. I want to write a review article about it some time this week for my blog, I like it so far. I've been using GnuCash for business purposes, but its too monstrous for personal finance. KMyMoney seems like a nice alternative. Works under Windows, by the way, if you install KDE for windows: http://windows.kde.org/

Comment: I'm in a Mac house, I just loaded KMM (to a Linux image) to see what it looked like. Honestly, I've used a spreadsheet for nearly 30 years, and it works well for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a detailed answer because I'm away from the computer where I use kMyMoney, but IIRC to add investments you have to create new transactions on the 'brokerage account' linked to your investment account.

Comment: You're right, I figured that out already and forgot to cancel the question:) Thanks